# java : get object name from scanner input

Tags: java, oop, object

I am teaching myself Java from books and videos from internet.
i know the bellow code is wrong but how can I make object name read from a variable  like this?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);

   String ObjectName=input.next();

   className ObjectName=new className ();
```

ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ , Pshemo ,Brian Vanover  i edit my question

i have class named BankAccount  and another main class with this code

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);

  System.out.println("Please Enter ID"); 
  int id=input.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Please Enter Name"); 
  String name = input.next();
  System.out.println("Please Enter Balance"); 
  double balance = input.nextDouble();

String client=input.next();
BankAccount client = new BankAccount (id,name,balance);// i know this code line is worng 

 client.printStatement();
```

Comment: It might be possible to do what you're asking, but that's not how programmers do things in general. Why do you want the variable name to be scanned? Since you're a beginner I'm just guessing that it's more likely that this isn't what you want.

Comment: "*i know this code line is worng*" Why do you think it is wrong? What error do you get? Also why are you trying to name `BankAccount` client if you already used `client` as name of String reference?

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking how to create instance of class based only on class name then you can try with

```
Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);
String className = input.nextLine();
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
Object o = clazz.newInstance();
```

Now if you pass `full.package.name.of.YourClass` and if this class has accessible no-argument constructor you should be able to create its instance via `newInstance` method.

---

Edit.

It seems that you want to store your object on some name provided by user. You can't do that explicitly as variable name, but you can make some map from `String` to `yourObject` using `Map` interface. Your code can look like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Please Enter ID");
int id = input.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please Enter Name");
String name = input.next();
System.out.println("Please Enter Balance");
double balance = input.nextDouble();

String client = input.next();
BankAccount clientAccount = new BankAccount(id, name, balance);

client.printStatement();

Map<String,BankAccount> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(client, clientAccount);
```

later you can just get account of client by using `map.get` and get account details like

```
map.get(client).getID();//assuming that you have getter for ID
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled by using an `enum` or `if-logic` If-logic will be ok if you expect a limited number of possible inputs:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);
  String objectName = input.next();

  if (ObjectName.equals("obj1")) {
    Obj1 myObject = new Obj1();
  } else {
    Obj2 myObject = new Obj2();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

First file name Out.java & second file name in.java
//first file's code start here

```
public class Out {

public static void main(String[] args) {


    in inObject =new in();
    inObject.ikl();

}



}

//second file's code start here
 import java.util.Scanner;

          public class in {

        public static int ikl() {

    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    int j=input.nextInt();
    System.out.println(j);

    return j;
}

   }
```

Comment: Hi there! It looks like your post doesn't answer the question at all, it looks like it's some sample code for using `Scanner` and not getting the Object name; the code seems to be very similar to the problem code in the question.